# Поменять цвет кнопки для Html хелпера

Tags: c#, bootstrap

На вьюхе есть Html хелпер который генерирует следующую разметку:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
<label class="btn btn-default">
<input name="Question" type="radio" value="1"></input>За</label>
<label class="btn btn-default">
<input name="Question" type="radio" value="2"></input>Против</label>
<label class="active btn btn-default">
<input checked="checked" name="Question" type="radio" value="3"></input>Воздержался</label>
</div>
```

Мне необходимо изменить цвет кнопки фона после нажатия, как это правильнее сделать?

Comment: Прописать в css класс с требуем цветом для кнопки, после нажатия присваивать этот класс кнопке.

Comment: Используйте css или jquery

Comment: Просто `btn-default::click{}`